# Edit earlier unpushed commits in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

When making many changes to a file, I want the changes to be neatly divided into easily-comprehensible commits for my colleagues to review. For example, commit 1 might be to factor out repeated code into a separate method, then after I make commits 2 and 3 (but before I push) I see another place where the new method can be incorporated, and I'd like to put this change in commit 1. Is this possible? If necessary I could then manually update commits 2 and 3 to incorporate this change.

Comment: Make a fourth commit with the changes for commit 1 and then in the _History_ view right-click commit 1 and choose _Interactive Rebase_. In the _Interactive Rebase_ view move the commit down and squash it with commit 1.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, it worked although not quite like that. I had to choose Interactive Rebase on the commit before commit 1, then move up commit 4 from 4th to 2nd position and right click and select Squash.

Comment: Yes, your right, the commit before commit 1, otherwise commit 1 cannot be squashed with another commit. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***Interactive Rebase*** for that as follows:

1. Make a **new commit** with the changes for commit 1
2. In the ***History*** view **right-click** the **commit before commit 1** and choose ***Interactive Rebase***
3. In the *Interactive Rebase* view **move the new commit to commit 1 and squash** both commits